# Implementation of componentRGBA method called by KVC when setting a UIColor property

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, uicolor, key-value-coding

I have a class with UIColor property named color and I want to set this property by string:

```
[label setValue:@"1.0 0.5 0.0 1.0" forKey:@"color"];
```

I know I need to convert the string to UIColor. I noticed that KVC calls a method named "componentRGBA" which is where I want to perform the conversion. So I added a category method on NSString:

```
-(UIColor*) componentRGBA
{
    CIColor* ciColor = [CIColor colorWithString:self];
    UIColor* uiColor = [UIColor colorWithCIColor:ciColor];
    return uiColor;
}
```

The method is called. However, `self` does not seem to be a valid NSString object because the call to colorWithString: crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS and so does every attempt of sending `self` an NSObject message (class, description, etc).

My suspicion is that the method signature of componentRGBA is not correct and therefore self isn't actually the string object. Though I could not find any reference by googling this method.

How do I properly implement `componentRGBA` so I can perform the color conversion automatically when a UIColor property is set to a NSString* value via KVC?

**Update:**

Interestingly, when I do this in the componentRGBA method:

```
CFShowStr((__bridge CFStringRef)self);
```

I receive the message:

> This is an NSString, not CFString

So it's supposed to be an NSString* yet I can't call any of its methods without crashing.

This simple test for example crashes:

```
NSLog(@"self = %@", [self description]);
```

The crash is in objc_msgSend with code=1 and address=0xffffffff (address varies from time to time).

In addition when I don't implement `componentRGBA` then KVC fails with the following message:

```
-[__NSCFConstantString componentRGBA]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc48f4
```

Comment: Have you considered a method or macro to parse the string?

Comment: yes but I would have to check specifically if the receiving property is of type UIColor and add a special case handling to convert string to UIColor instead of just relying on KVC to perform the conversion as needed

Comment: Ok, so my problem here is that there isn't any conversion done. It simply takes the string and assigns it to a UIColor property since both are objects, and the string treated as color wrecks havoc for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be only of academic interest, as you probably don't want to rely on
an undocumented method, but the following implementation seems to work:

```
// This structure is returned by the (undocumened) componentRGBA
// method of UIColor. The elements are "float", even on 64-bit,
// so we cannot use CGFloat here.
struct rgba {
    float r, g, b, a;
};

@interface UIColor (ComponentRGBA)
-(struct rgba) componentRGBA;
@end

@interface NSString (ComponentRGBA)
-(struct rgba) componentRGBA;
@end

@implementation NSString (ComponentRGBA)
-(struct rgba) componentRGBA
{
    CIColor* ciColor = [CIColor colorWithString:self];
    UIColor* uiColor = [UIColor colorWithCIColor:ciColor];
    return [uiColor componentRGBA];
}
@end
```

I figured this out with the help of the sample project of your (now deleted)
question [KVC: what does the 'componentRGBA' method do when setting a color property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190962/kvc-what-does-the-componentrgba-method-do-when-setting-a-color-property). The key point was that (as one could see by
inspecting the stack backtrace) the `componentRGBA` method is called via
`objc_msgSend_stret()`, which means that it returns a `struct` and not some `id`.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: You are welcome, it was fun! - I just noticed that the `struct rgba` must use `float`, not `CGFloat`. Otherwise it crashes on 64-bit. I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I implemented this method in CCColor and can now use it in place of UIColor. This is awesome, saves me from having to write a bunch of property setters/getters to do the conversion.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: But keep in mind that you are relying on an undocumented implementation detail ...

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for sure. Right now it's just awesome to be able to convert practically any object ad-hoc to UIColor/NSColor even when using KVC.

Comment: This is of academic sweetness..... I never got far enough to `objc_msgSend_stret()`...+1.. I hope tomorrow Apple would write a few words for this so that it became "documented". Even words as few as _"Description: componentRGBA. Use it if you want. Availability: iOS (7.0 and later)."_..

Comment: @MartinR Just noticed: using `CGFloat` shouldn't crash? It is a `double` on 64-bit and a `float` on 32-bit. But `float` is only 32 bit?

Comment: @Unheilig: If `componentRGBA` is expected to return a struct of 4 floats (which seems to be the case from my test) then we cannot return a struct of 4 doubles instead. A struct return value is (usually) written to an address supplied by the caller, so returning a struct of different size would corrupt the caller's stack.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: You probably figured that out by yourself, but you can "forward" the componentRGBA call from your class to UIColor. See updated answer.